How to increase the revolutions of the DC micromotor model 180 12 volts
I need to make the motor draw 12 volts and 2 amps at idle at 40,000 rpm.

I don't know how to properly retrofit an existing model 180 DC micromotor.
Specifically:

What thickness to take the wire
Which wire cross-section is better, for example, one 3mm wire or three 1mm wires wound into one?
How to start winding correctly and how to lay the wire for the best performance?
How many turns should be wound for the selected conductor?
Which magnets are better to use: ferrite or neodymium?
Which form of graphite brushes is better: flat or recessed under the rotor?

The friction zones of the rotor will be lubricated. A wheel will be attached to the motor shaft, which will transmit the torque.
Maybe you know of ready-made configurations for such engines, then just describe what you used and what results you got.

"12 volts and 2 amps at idle at 40,000 rpm." That should probably be "when unloaded". "Idle" suggests stopped. 12 V x 2 A = 24 W which is a fair bit of heat for something that small to dissipate - especially when it's not doing any work. It's not clear how you hope to replace the magnets or the brushes.

I saw on aliexpress a neodymium magnet of the same size as the ferrite ones that are in the motor. I was thinking of erasing the graphite reshaping brushes to change the contact area with the rotor, but not sure if I should do that at all.

Don't even think of rewinding that motor: it's not worth it and you're likely to mess it up.
Instead, buy a motor that meets your needs.
If by "increase the revolutions" you actually mean "increase the speed", and if you really must use that very motor, then you should know that the top speed (no load) of a PM DC motor is proportional to the applied voltage. Doubling the voltage in theory doubles the speed. However, the speed is limited my mechanical concerns (it can fall apart) and insulation (arcing). You can also increase the speed with a gear train.

This is an experimental engine, it will not be under a long load for more than 5 minutes, and it is not a pity if it does not work. I would buy such an engine, but I don't know where to find the right one.

For your information, in English, "engine" is powered by fuel (petrol), and "motor" is powered by electricity. What you have there is a "motor".

Unless you're speaking the American dialect, in which case 'motor' is often used to refer to both the electric and 'gas'(oline) fueled devices ... :p

Sorry, I'm just not good at English, so I'm using a translator. So I mixed up the motors
